# Get GMT String from current Date

Tags: javascript, date, gmt, datejs

I am able to get the output format that I need, but not the correct time. I need it in GMT (which is +4 hours)

```
var dt = new Date();
var dt2 = dt.toString('yyyyMMddhhmmss');
```

Any ideas? The output looks like:

```
20120403031408
```

I am able to get the GMT in standard string format by doing:

```
dt.toUTCString();
```

but im unable to convert it back to the yyyyMMddhhmmss string

EDIT: I am using the date.js library

Comment: What library or script are you using to get `toString(format)`? The [standard method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) doesn't acknowledge any arguments.

Comment: Apologies, im using date.js. Edited the Question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date.js`'s [`toString(format)`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) doesn't have an option to specify "UTC" when formatting dates. The [method itself](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/core.js) (at the bottom of the file) never references any of `Date`'s [`getUTC...` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2), which would be necessary to support such an option.

You may consider using a different library, such as Steven Levithan's [`dateFormat`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format). With it, you can either prefix the `format` with `UTC:`, or pass `true` after the `format`:

```
var utcFormatted = dateFormat(new Date(), 'UTC:yyyyMMddhhmmss');
var utcFormatted = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyyMMddhhmmss', true);

// also
var utcFormatted = new Date().format('yyyyMMddhhmmss', true);
```

You can also write your own function, as [Dominic demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9999992/15031).

Comment: Worked great with Steven Levithan's library. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the `getUTC` functions :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */  
function ISODateString(d){  
  function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n }
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-'  
       + pad(d.getUTCMonth() +1) + '-'  
       + pad(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T'  
       + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':'  
       + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'  
       + pad(d.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z'  
}  

var d = new Date();  
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28T19:03:12Z
```